# How to override an attrs class instance with another one when the values are not None

Tags: python, python-attrs

My goal is to be able to merge multiple instances of the same `attrs` class and skip 'None' values.

This allows me to create default values and later override them when I need to.

An example of the expected code-

```py
from attr import attrs

@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class A:
    a: int = None
    b: int = None

instance_1 = A(a=1, b=2)
instance_2 = A(b=3)

# Expected result
instance_3 = merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2)
# instance_3 = A(a=1, b=3)
```

The best solution I currently found was the following-

```py
from attr import attrs


@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class A:
    a: int = None
    b: int = None


def merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2):
    dict_1 = instance_1.__dict__
    dict_2 = instance_2.__dict__
    new_values = {}
    for key in dict_1:
        new_values[key] = dict_2[key] if dict_2[key] is not None else dict_1[key]
    return A(**new_values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance_1 = A(a=1, b=2)
    instance_2 = A(b=3)

    instance_3 = merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2)
    print(instance_3)
```

Which kind of feels like a hack. If anyone has a simpler solution I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

This is cleaner

```py
def merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2):
    dict_1 = instance_1.__dict__
    dict_2 = instance_2.__dict__
    new_values = {k: dict_2[k] or dict_1[k] for k in dict_1}
    return A(**new_values)
```

Since this function is strictly related to class `A`, you can make it a classmethod

```py
from attr import attrs

@attrs(auto_attribs=True)
class A:
    a: int = None
    b: int = None

    @classmethod
    def merge_instances(cls, instance_1, instance_2):
        dict_1 = instance_1.__dict__
        dict_2 = instance_2.__dict__
        return cls(
            **{k: dict_2[k] or dict_1[k] for k in dict_1}
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance_1 = A(a=1, b=2)
    instance_2 = A(b=3)

    instance_3 = A.merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2)
```

Comment: This would replace everything with the values of dict2 if they are not none.

Comment: Following his `new_values[key] = dict_2[key] if dict_2[key] is not None else dict_1[key]`, I think that this is what @Guy is asking for

Comment: Yes I know this is not a proper _merge_, it's just an arbitrary way to create a new instance starting from two of them

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using attrs, this is more idiomatic:

```py
from attrs import define, fields


@define
class A:
    a: int = None
    b: int = None


instance_1 = A(a=1, b=2)
instance_2 = A(b=3)


def merge_instances(i1: A, i2: A) -> A:
    kw = {}
    for f in fields(A):
        v = getattr(i2, f.name)
        kw[f.name] = v if v is not None else getattr(i1, f.name)

    return A(**kw)


assert A(a=1, b=3) == merge_instances(instance_1, instance_2)
```

Another possibility that is one line longer, but feels cleaner to me is to use `attrs.evolve()`:

```py
def merge_instances(i1: A, i2: A) -> A:
    kw = {}
    for f in fields(A):
        v = getattr(i2, f.name)
        if v is not None:
            kw[f.name] = v

    return evolve(i1, **kw)
```

Even nicer if you get to use the walrus:

```py
def merge_instances(i1: A, i2: A) -> A:
    kw = {}
    for f in fields(A):
        if (v := getattr(i2, f.name)) is not None:
            kw[f.name] = v

    return evolve(i1, **kw)
```

which could be simplified even further :

```py
def merge_instances(i1: A, i2: A) -> A:
    return evolve(
        i1,
        **{
            f.name: v
            for f in fields(A)
            if (v := getattr(i2, f.name)) is not None
        },
    )
```